# core dump stack indicates SIGSEGV due to vector<vector<int>> usage

Tags: c++11, coredump, bucket-sort

I have a code snippet that is behaving weirdly. The code is simply aiming to implement radix and bucket sort. When I comment in the main one of either sort and run it works perfectly. But when I enable both of them i am getting a core dump. And the weird part is core dump as indicated by the stack is crossing over into the stl_vector.h.

The code reference is here:- https://rextester.com/RUUDP10453

When i enable only one of the sorts like below in main it works fine.

```
  //doRadixSort(arr, size);
    doBucketSort(arr, size);
   or
  doRadixSort(arr, size);
  //doBucketSort(arr, size);
```

But when both are enabled there is segmentation fault after both sorts are completed as indicated by the

```
cout << "i am here at exit" << endl;
```

The core dump stack indicates some reference/hint at vector of vector buckets. But i have properly allocated and reserved it the required memory. so why this is happening i need some expertise to dig out. I have tried debugging this in eclipse CDT C++ for about 2 hrs with no lead.

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  _int_free (av=0x7f66d702eb00 <main_arena>, p=0xf98020, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3976
3976                  >= ((char *) av->top + chunksize(av->top)), 0))
(gdb) where
#0  _int_free (av=0x7f66d702eb00 <main_arena>, p=0xf98020, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3976
#1  0x00007f66d6cf33dc in __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2966
#2  0x00000000004030fa in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::deallocate (this=0x7fffc6ffa060, __p=0xf98030) at /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/new_allocator.h:110
#3  0x0000000000402d23 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::deallocate (__a=..., __p=0xf98030, __n=10) at /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/alloc_traits.h:442
#4  0x00000000004027ac in std::_Vector_base<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fffc6ffa060, __p=0xf98030, __n=10)
    at /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_vector.h:178
#5  0x00000000004025e4 in std::_Vector_base<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fffc6ffa060, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_vector.h:160
#6  0x000000000040211d in std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::~vector (this=0x7fffc6ffa060, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_vector.h:427
#7  0x0000000000401d4b in doBucketSort (arr=0x7fffc6ffa100, size=@0x7fffc6ffa0f8: 12) at tako.cpp:97
#8  0x0000000000401e29 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffc6ffa218) at tako.cpp:141
(gdb)
```

Comment: In both functions you did the same mistake - `reserve` was used instead of `resize`. `reserve` changes the capacity of vector, size is untouched. So before and after calling `reserve` size of `buckets` vector is 0, then you call `operator[]` for empty vector it leads to UB.

Comment: I got your point , it works now!!! It was all due to only memory being reserved and actually proper vector interface not being used to initialize the vectors inside the vector.  Now i have below code.

 // Create the 10 buckets as indicated below.
 vector<vector<int>> buckets;
 vector<int> emptyVec = { };
 buckets.reserve(10);
 for(unsigned int i=0; i<=9; ++i)
 {
  buckets[i].reserve(size);
  buckets.push_back(emptyVec);
 }

Comment: can you upvote the question so that it can help me build my StackOverflow points? I could not see this question hence asked.

Comment: I am very sorry rafix07, I jumped in excitement bit too early. Could you please take a look at my code modifications at https://rextester.com/RUUDP10453 , After a few more runs its again back to dumping the core. I am still unclear on which piece i am missing in the cleanup. I do vector clear which removes all items and then shrink to fit which releases the memory. still it is dumping the core and failing to run. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Call `buckets.resize(10);` instead of `buckets.reserve(10);`. So should be `vector<vector<int>> buckets;`, `buckets.resize(10);`, `for(unsigned int i=0; i<=9; ++i) buckets[i].reserve(size);` in both functions.

Comment: worked perfectly!!! no memory leaks as well. Excellent I will step through and try to understand the bit now. Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, I found the below also works which is equivalent to the resize function.

```
vector<vector<int>> buckets; 
constexpr size_t size=10, bucketSize=10;
buckets.reserve(bucketSize); 
for(unsigned int i=0; i<=bucketSize; ++i) 
    buckets.push_back({ });  
for(unsigned int i=0; i<=bucketSize; ++i) 
    buckets[i].reserve(size);
```